DocFX references to parameter type instead of method
I use DocFX to generate documentation for my library. The following class extends AsyncTaskTarget:
public class AsyncUdpTarget : AsyncTaskTarget
{
    // extend the base class
}

So, it inherits AsyncTaskTarget.WriteAsyncTask(IList<LogEventInfo>, CancellationToken) method.
The DocFX generates the following YAML file for the AsyncUdpTarget:
### YamlMime:ManagedReference
items:
# ...
- uid: NLog.Targets.AsyncTaskTarget.WriteAsyncTask(System.Collections.Generic.IList{NLog.LogEventInfo},System.Threading.CancellationToken)
  commentId: M:NLog.Targets.AsyncTaskTarget.WriteAsyncTask(System.Collections.Generic.IList{NLog.LogEventInfo},System.Threading.CancellationToken)
  parent: NLog.Targets.AsyncTaskTarget
  isExternal: true
  href: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1
  name: WriteAsyncTask(IList<LogEventInfo>, CancellationToken)
  nameWithType: AsyncTaskTarget.WriteAsyncTask(IList<LogEventInfo>, CancellationToken)
  fullName: NLog.Targets.AsyncTaskTarget.WriteAsyncTask(System.Collections.Generic.IList<NLog.LogEventInfo>, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
  nameWithType.vb: AsyncTaskTarget.WriteAsyncTask(IList(Of LogEventInfo), CancellationToken)
  fullName.vb: NLog.Targets.AsyncTaskTarget.WriteAsyncTask(System.Collections.Generic.IList(Of NLog.LogEventInfo), System.Threading.CancellationToken)
  name.vb: WriteAsyncTask(IList(Of LogEventInfo), CancellationToken)
  spec.csharp:
  - uid: NLog.Targets.AsyncTaskTarget.WriteAsyncTask(System.Collections.Generic.IList{NLog.LogEventInfo},System.Threading.CancellationToken)
    name: WriteAsyncTask
    isExternal: true
  - name: (
  - uid: System.Collections.Generic.IList`1
    name: IList
    isExternal: true
    href: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1
  - name: <
  - uid: NLog.LogEventInfo
    name: LogEventInfo
    isExternal: true
  - name: '>'
  - name: ','
  - name: " "
  - uid: System.Threading.CancellationToken
    name: CancellationToken
    isExternal: true
    href: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken
  - name: )
  spec.vb:
  - uid: NLog.Targets.AsyncTaskTarget.WriteAsyncTask(System.Collections.Generic.IList{NLog.LogEventInfo},System.Threading.CancellationToken)
    name: WriteAsyncTask
    isExternal: true
  - name: (
  - uid: System.Collections.Generic.IList`1
    name: IList
    isExternal: true
    href: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1
  - name: (
  - name: Of
  - name: " "
  - uid: NLog.LogEventInfo
    name: LogEventInfo
    isExternal: true
  - name: )
  - name: ','
  - name: " "
  - uid: System.Threading.CancellationToken
    name: CancellationToken
    isExternal: true
    href: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken
  - name: )
# ...

Note, it creates hyperlink to https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1. I also tried to define custom xrefmap with the following content:
### YamlMime:ManagedReference
references:
# ...
- uid: NLog.Targets.AsyncTaskTarget.WriteAsyncTask(System.Collections.Generic.IList`1,System.Threading.CancellationToken)
  name: WriteAsyncTask(IList{LogEventInfo}, CancellationToken)
  href: https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v5.0.0/html/M_NLog_Targets_AsyncTaskTarget_WriteAsyncTask_1.htm
  fullName: NLog.Targets.AsyncTaskTarget.WriteAsyncTask(System.Collections.Generic.IList`1,System.Threading.CancellationToken)
# ...

But it doesn't help. DocFX makes reference to type definition of the first parameter  instead of the method definition. How to fix the issue?

I have found temporary solution. It's possible to add content file with uid of problematic member and redirect it to the correct URL:
---
uid: NLog.Targets.AsyncTaskTarget.WriteAsyncTask(System.Collections.Generic.IList`1,System.Threading.CancellationToken)
redirect_url: https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v5.0.0/html/M_NLog_Targets_AsyncTaskTarget_WriteAsyncTask_1.htm
---

But I don't like the solution.
